# DO was unexpected at this time. error 255

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that cleans out all user's cache files.

```
REM Set file locations for temp/history/cookies files.
SET SRC1=C:\Users
SET SRC2=AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files
SET SRC3=AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History
SET SRC4=AppData\Local\Temp
SET SRC5=AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies
SET SRC6=AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Low\Content.IE5

REM begin cleaning internet files
echo cleaning temporary internet files
FOR /D %%X IN ("%SRC1%\*") DO FOR /D %%Y IN ("%%X\%SRC2%\*.*") DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%Y"

REM begin cleaning history files
echo cleaning history
FOR /D %%X IN ("%SRC1%\*") DO FOR /D %%Y IN ("%%X\%SRC3%\*.*") DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%Y"

REM begin cleaning windows temp files
echo cleaning windows temp files
FOR /D %%X IN ("%SRC1%\*") DO FOR /D %%Y IN ("%%X\%SRC4%\*.*") DO RMDIR /F /S /Q "%%Y"
FOR /D %%X IN ("%SRC1%\*") DO FOR %%Y IN ("%%X\%SRC3%\*.*") DO DEL /F /S /Q "%%Y"
FOR /D %%X IN ("%SRC1%\*") DO FOR %%Y IN ("%%X\%SRC4%\*.*") DO DEL /F /S /Q "%%Y"

REM begin cleaning Cookies folder
echo cleaning Cookies
FOR /D %%X IN ("%SRC1%\*") DO FOR %%Y IN ("%%X\%SRC5%\*.*") DO DEL /F /S /Q "%%Y"

REM del C:\temp folder
FOR /D %%X IN ("%windir%\temp\*") DO RMDIR /F /S /Q "%%X"
DEL /f /s /q "%windir%\temp"

REM Del Temp Internet Files
FOR /D %%x in ("%SRC6%\*") DO FOR %%Y DO DEL /F /S /Q "%%Y"
FOR /D %%x in ("%SRC1%\*") DO FOR %%Y IN ("%%X\%SRC6%\*.*") DO DEL /F /S /Q "%%Y"

:END
```

When running this via `psexec`, I am getting the following error:

```
DO was unexpected at this time.
batch file exited on PCNAME with error code 255.
```

On other Windows 7 and XP machines, I'm able to run this and I get an error that states it was successful.

This is the first time I've seen this error but I can't seem to narrow down the error.
Can anyone lend a second pair of eyes?

Comment: `"an error that states it was successful."`

Comment: You can't get "an error that states it was successful", as an error would prevent it from being successful. Also, you have far too many DO statements with no information that allows it to be narrowed down to a single possible issue. Insert ECHO statements that you can use to isolate the problem to a more focused area of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the lines below in your code.

```
...
REM Del Temp Internet Files
FOR /D %%x in ("%SRC6%\*") DO FOR %%Y DO DEL /F /S /Q "%%Y"
...
```

You are missing the `IN (...)` part of your nested `FOR` loop.

Hence: `DO was unexpected at this time.`